# Localizing Display Name in TimeZoneInfo object for displaying timezones in different cultures

Tags: c#, localization, timezone

We are trying to localize display name in Microsft [TimezoneInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.getsystemtimezones?view=netframework-4.7.2) object which is Windows specific. (for example : **(UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)**) to different cultures and bind the values to a drop-down. As this method doesn't support localization, we tried using [TimeZoneNames nuget package](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneNames). We could get standard name ("Pacific Standard Time") localized from this package but not the Display name and we could not find proper identifier and mappings between object returned by Microsoft and Objects returned from [this package](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneNames) methods.

Can anyone please suggest any solutions or other alternatives. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to get localized values from `TimeZoneInfo.DisplayName` without changing the active language/locale of the underlying Windows operating system.

However, I've now included this functionality to [TimeZoneNames](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneNames) with version 4.0.0.  You can either get a list of time zones and their localized display names with `TZNames.GetDisplayNames`, or you can get a single localized display name with `TZNames.GetDisplayNameForTimeZone`.